# why free function causes infinite loop?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I created a program in c which :

1. Creates a simple linked list in c in which I store letters
2. Print the content of every node
3. delete the last node
4. Print the content of the list again

The problem is with the "delete_last" function because prints in terminal an infinite loop (I believe that the problem is invoked when I use free funtion.)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
    
    
typedef struct node {
    char xar;
    struct node *next;
}Node;
    
    
void insert_list(Node **head , int len)
{   
        char x;
        Node **list; 
        Node *node1 , *node2;
        node1=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        printf("Give 5 characters : ");
        x=getchar();
        node1->xar = x;
        node1->next=NULL;
        list=&node1;
        int i=0;
    
        for(i=1 ; i < len ; i++)
        {   x=getchar(); 
            node2 = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
            node2->xar = x;
            node2->next = NULL;
            (*list) -> next = node2;
            list = &(*list) -> next ;  
         } 
         
         *head=node1;
         
    }
void print_list(Node *head)
{
    Node**lpp;
    for(lpp=&head ; *lpp!=NULL ; lpp=&(*lpp)->next)
    {
        printf("\n the chars are %c" , (*lpp)->xar);
    }

}
    
void delete_last(Node *head)
{
        Node **lpp;
        lpp=&head;
        while((*lpp)->next!=NULL)
        {
            lpp=&(*lpp)->next;
        }
        free(*lpp);
    }
        
        
    
int main()
{
        Node *kefali ; 
        kefali = NULL;
        insert_list(&kefali , 5);
        print_list(kefali);
        printf("\n");
        delete_last(kefali);
        print_list(kefali);
        
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: This code must be C++, not C, because you cannot use `node` as type in this code as C. (only `struct node` and `Node` are available)

Comment: I get a crash in `print_list`. Try adding `*lpp = NULL;` after the `free` line.

Comment: You should rewrite `delete_last(Node *head)` as `delete_last(Node **head)` and call it with `delete_last(&kefali);` if you actually want to change the list.

Comment: @RetiredNinja You are right so when I want to use `free()` function has to set the pointer to NULL before?

Comment: @BrechtSanders why I has to use pointer to pointer I do not want to change ` *head ` inside of my function 
Why If i want to change the list has to use pointer to pointer ?

Comment: As @RetiredNinja said you need to set the last node to `NULL`. When deleting the last node you need to be able to set the list pointer to `NULL`. If you don't use a pointer to a pointer you will only set the copy of the pointer inside the function to `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

You mustn't access to freed objects.

In the `delete_last` functon, you called `free()` for one of the nodes, but you didn't update any pointers there. This will have the following call of `print_list` access a freed object, invoking *undefined behavior*.

You should add

```
*lpp = NULL;
```

after

```
free(*lpp);
```

To get the freed node out of the list.

Note that this won't work for removing the first (only) element in the list because the `head` is passed as a copy. You should change the function to accept a pointer to the head pointer to enable it remove the first element.

Comment: It needs to track the one element before end as well

Comment: @0___________ Why? Track for what purpose?

Comment: you need to change the previous element `next` to NULL. Finding the last element is not enough.

Comment: @0___________ `lpp` is a pointer to the `next` of the previous element, so it looks enough to use that.

Comment: if there is only one element in the list it invokes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Your `delete_last` lacks a way of telling that the last element was deleted. Either pass a pointer to `head` or return a new `head`.

Further, it's way to complicated. Using `lpp` as pointer to pointer is not necessary - it only complicates the code. **Keep it simple**.

Here is an example which returns the new `head`.

```
Node* delete_last(Node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL) return NULL;   // empty list
    if (head->next == NULL)
    {
        // Only one element...
        free(head);
        return NULL;
    }
    Node *prev = head;
    Node *lpp = prev->next;
    while (lpp->next)
    {
        prev = lpp;
        lpp = prev->next;
    }
    prev->next = NULL;
    free(lpp);
    return head;
}
```

and call it like:

```
head = delete_last(head);
```

Here is an example which takes a pointer to `head`.

```
Node* delete_last(Node **head)
{
    if (head == NULL) exit(1);       // illegal call
    if (*head == NULL) return NULL;  // empty list
    if ((*head)->next == NULL)
    {
        // Only one element...
        free(*head);
        *head = NULL;
        return;
    }
    Node *prev = *head;
    Node *lpp = prev->next;
    while (lpp->next)
    {
        prev = lpp;
        lpp = prev->next;
    }
    prev->next = NULL;
    free(lpp);
}
```

and call it like:

```
delete_last(&head);
```

Answer (score -1):

1. You do not update the previous node (you need to keep track on it when iterating)
2. This makes no sense as you take reference to the local variable head and it does not change the the head of list when last element is deleted.

```
Node **lpp;
lpp=&head;
```

To prevent double-pointer function returns the head. Assign it when called. If return value is NULL the last element was deleted

```
Node *delete_last(Node *head)
{
        Node *lpp = NULL, *prev;

        if(head)
        {
            lpp=head -> next;
            prev = head;
            while(lpp->next)
            {
                prev = lpp;
                lpp = lpp -> next;
            }
            if(prev == head && lpp == NULL)
            {
                free(head);
                head = NULL; //empty list
            }
            else
            {
                free(lpp);
                prev -> next = NULL;
            }
        }
    free(lpp);
    return head;
}
```

You can also use double pointer to modify the head when needed:

```
void delete_last(Node **head)
{
    Node *lpp = NULL;

    if(head && *head)
    {
        if(!(*head) -> next)
        {
            free(*head);
            *head = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            lpp = *head;
            while(lpp -> next -> next)
            {
                lpp = lpp -> next;
            }
            free(lpp -> next);
            lpp -> next = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why has to return head I do not modify head but one part of the linked list 
so why has to return head that is a point that I had misunderstood?

Comment: if the list has only one element and you delete it the head has to become NULL.  Call it `kefali = elete_last(kefali);`

Comment: The indentation is bad but as far as I can see the first example will call `free` with an uninitialized value in case `head` is NULL

Comment: Here `while(lpp->next)` the pointer `lpp` may be NULL so dereference it is bad

Comment: Here `if(prev == head && lpp == NULL)` the pointer `lpp` can't be NULL because the `while` condition would have dereferenced a NULL pointer.

Comment: Second code: `lpp -> next;` --> `lpp -> next = NULL`; ?